# Next Js - Inner pages loading the home page content on Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

We are developing a website with Next Js. Home page and Inner pages are loading fine in local as well as the build deployed in AWS S3. But when we refresh any inner page or open it in a new tab, it is loading the content of the home page where the URL is of the inner page URL. We tried to reproduce this issue locally but in local it is working fine.

Comment: Could you please provide code samples and/or screenshots to whom it might give some ideas about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `trailingSlash` in your `next.config.js` file to remove this problem on your application. By default Next.js will redirect URLs with trailing slashes to their counterpart without a trailing slash.

In next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true, // it should be true
  ....

}
```

With this option set, urls like `/about` will redirect to `/about/`.